# Как сохранить информации в Лист на ASP.NET MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здраствуйте.
Я новичок в MVC.
У меня такой класс есть.

```
class UserInfo
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Surname{get;set;}
}
```

И меня такой контроллер есть.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        List<UserInfo> Users = new List<UserInfo>(); 
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

       public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Users.Add(userInfo);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
```

И каждый когда я нажимаю кнопку Create в браузере List Users оказывается пустым.
Почему так происходит?
В чем проблема?
Как сохранит данные в листе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что экземпляр контроллера создается приложением при каждом новом запросе. И так как список `List<UserInfo> Users` не является статическим, то при каждом запросе он создается заново вместе с контроллером и оказывается пустым.

Самый простой способ сохранить данные между запросами в вашем случае - сделать список статическим. В итоге он будет создан один раз, при первом обращении к контроллеру:

```
static List<UserInfo> Users = new List<UserInfo>();
```